# PHP Contact form not being sent to email

Tags: php, forms, email

I realize there are lots of threads covering this topic, but I've looked at several and can't seem to figure out my issue. I have a contact form that worked when I first put it up, and since then, with no changes to the code, has stopped working correctly.

A user can fill out the form and submit it, but the form is never sent as an email (or at least it's never received.) Below is the code I am working with. Any help with this would be very much appreciated. Also, don't think this would matter, but the website is hosted through godaddy because that is where the client had already purchased their hosting. Let me know if I need to clarify anything further.

**Code from contact.php**

```
<div id="contactForm" class="clearfix">
            <?php
                //init variables
                $cf = array();
                $sr = false;

                if(isset($_SESSION['cf_returndata'])){
                    $cf = $_SESSION['cf_returndata'];
                    $sr = true;
                }
            ?>
            <ul id="errors" class="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? 'visible' : ''; ?>">
                <li id="info">There were some problems with your form submission:</li>
                <?php 
                if(isset($cf['errors']) && count($cf['errors']) > 0) :
                    foreach($cf['errors'] as $error) :
                ?>
                <li><?php echo $error ?></li>
                <?php
                    endforeach;
                endif;
                ?>
            </ul>
            <p id="success" class="<?php echo ($sr && $cf['form_ok']) ? 'visible' : ''; ?>">Thanks for your message! We will get back to you ASAP!</p>
        <form action="contact-process.php" method="post" id="contaxForm">
            <div class="rowElem clearfix">
                <label for="name">Name:<em class="warning">*</em></label>
                <input id="name" name="name" class="input-text" type="text" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['name'] : '' ?>" placeholder="John Doe" autofocus required>                    
            </div>     

            <div class="rowElem clearfix">
                <label for="email">Email:<em class="warning">*</em></label>
                <input id="email" name="email" class="input-text" type="email" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['email'] : '' ?>" placeholder="joe@email.com" required>
            </div>       

            <div class="rowElem clearfix">
                <label for="subject">Subject: </label>
                <select name="subject">
                    <option value="General Inquiry">General Inquiry</option>
                    <option value="Reviews">Review</option>
                    <option value="Wholesale">Wholesale</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="rowElem clearfix">
                <label for="message">Message:</label>
                <textarea class="large" rows="5" id="message" name="message" class="input-text" type="text" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['message'] : '' ?>" placeholder=""></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="rowElem">
                <label> &nbsp; </label>
                <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit!" />
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php unset($_SESSION['cf_returndata']); ?> <!--this allows the form to be reset when leaving or refreshing page--> 
    </div>
```

**And here is the code from the file contact-process.php**

```
<?php  
if( isset($_POST) ){  

//form validation vars  
$formok = true;  
$errors = array();  

//submission data  
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
$date = date('d/m/Y');  
$time = date('H:i:s');

//form data
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
// $device = $_POST['device'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//form validation to go here....

//validate name is not empty
if(empty($name)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a name";
}

//validate email address is not empty
if(empty($email)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered an email address";
//validate email address is valid
}elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a valid email address";
}
//validate message is not empty
if(empty($message)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a message model";
}

//send email if all is ok
if($formok){        
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers = "From: email@yahoo.com" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n";
    $to = "email@website.com";
    $email_subject .= "New Submission from your website";

    $emailbody = "<p>You have recieved a new message from the contact form on your website.</p>
                  <p><strong>Name: </strong> {$name} </p>
                  <p><strong>Email Address: </strong> {$email} </p>
                  <p><strong>Subject: </strong> {$subject} </p>
                  <p><strong>Message: </strong> {$message} </p>
                  <p>This message was sent on {$date} at {$time}</p>";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$emailbody,$headers);       
}

//what we need to return back to our form
$returndata = array(
    'posted_form_data' => array(
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'message' => $message
    ),
    'form_ok' => $formok,
    'errors' => $errors
);

//if this is not an ajax request
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest'){

    //set session variables
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['cf_returndata'] = $returndata;

    //redirect back to form
    header('location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

}
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe your host disabled the mail() function?

Comment: I think also that something should have been changed. For example php version, configuration, firewall policy, mailer settings. Maybe you could try to use for example phpmailer which supports easier debug, and more mail sending option. (Sending via smtp directly it would work...)

Comment: PHP's `mail()` function is notoriously unreliable. Look at [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/). GoDaddy are also not the most reliable of hosting services. They may well have disable your outbound email.

Comment: Possible help from a [GoDaddy forum](http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/php-mail-problems-2/): "... send the email using a From email address that uses a domain name associated with your hosting plan. [Otherwise] it can be viewed as spoofing and my be rejected by email servers."

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will look into phpmailer and if i can get that working. I tried messing around with it a little, but keep getting errors, so I'm going to have to dig in further. PHP is not a strength of mine. 

I tried setting the email from address to an email of the same domain as the website, but that didn't help anything. 

Thanks again for the help, and I will see what I can do from here.

Answer (score 0):

All mail() does is queue the email in the system's MTA. Check your MTA log (eg. var/log/sendmail, etc..).

Is the line with mail() being hit?

```
 echo 'got here'; exit();
```

I use this to debug all the time. It will quickly let you know if the code is reaching a particular line.

You should figure this stuff out before posting your question, because if the problem is with mail(), none of your other code is related to the problem here.

As for fixing your mail server, that's not a programming question. You can look into using a 3rd party smtp server instead of your system's MTA.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Josh. Unfortunately for me, php is not one of my strengths, so debugging it is over my head. Don't even know where to start. I tried to find the MTA log on godaddy, but couldn't figure out what or where it was. 

I downloaded phpmailer and am going to see if i can figure that out. Appreciate the guidance!